# Restart CSS3 animation without JavaScript?

Tags: css, css-animations

Is there any way to restart a CSS3 animation when clicked without using JavaScript?

Comment: @JanDvorak That was quick, but not the answer I was hoping for! ;)  I didn't think so, either, but I thought maybe someone else knew of some way to do it.

Comment: I can upvote; luckily there will come a person to _prove_ this impossible ;-)

Comment: do you have a fiddle for an example HTML+CSS3 Animation to see what you have?

Comment: @BastianRang I'm messing around in the Tryit Editor on w3schools.com. This http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation3 is the animation I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the [Checkbox Hack](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) though it generally isn't encouraged.

Might be worth looking into however. It is an intriguing use of html and css.

**EDIT**

After a bit of play, I came up with [this](http://jsbin.com/ilexek/1/edit) example. The hardest part is actually just resetting the animation without javascript, not registering the click event. To get around it I duplicated the animation to a second css rule that begins when the checkbox is hit.

There may be a better way to do it, but this would theoretically work, aside from being a bit unconventional :)

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Added an example of it working, so it is for sure possible, though probably not widely supported and so on and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for that example. I played with it and tried setting the opacity of the checkbox to zero and I changed the text from "Do Something" to "Play", and I had what I wanted. Thanks again for that example!!

Answer (score 2):

there is a [css-trick](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/) summarizing some methods of doing this. You can try the `:target` pseudo-class instead of the checkbox-hack.

**Edit**:
Made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VGLAc/) of the example using the `:target` pseudo-class.

Comment: OK, so what makes the animation restart?

Comment: you need two separate animations, looking identical. you bind one to the default div and one to `div:target`. A link to your div-id does the rest.

Comment: Nice! Hadn't thought of that approach.